# css image background positioning

Tags: css, list, styling

I'm struggling with a css challenge. I have a list with a arrow bullet. I want the arrow bullet align at the first line. This arrow bullet is set via the background-image like this:

```
.linklist a { 
  display: block; 
  padding: 0 0 0 8px; 
  background: transparent url("../images/css/arrow-left.png") no-repeat 0; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  outline: none; }
```

Result is:

[image]

When I remove display: block it shows arrow bullet on the first line, like I want. But now, the second line is indented. I want vertical alignment between the two lines and the arrow bullet aligned at the first line. Is there something i'm overlooking how to style this?

[image]

Hope anybody can help me?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 5):

CSS

```
background-position: left top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
background: transparent url("../images/css/arrow-left.png") 0 -4px no-repeat;
```

With `0` being the left background position and `-4px` being the top one.

Answer (score 0):

You need use background-position :

```
.linklist a { 
  display: block; 
  padding: 0 0 0 8px; 
  background: transparent url("../images/css/arrow-left.png") no-repeat 0; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  outline: none;
  /*new*/
  background-position: 15px 20px
 }
```